# Different Stylesheets for Differently Sized Browser Windows

Tags: css, responsive-design

I've seen this question floating around, and have seen many good answers but some don't work for me as they don't achieve what I really want, and the one I've found that does, just isn't working for a hopefully-soon-to-be-discovered reason.

So,

As the title suggests I want to load different style sheets for different browser dimensions. The goal being 4 major stylesheets.

1. general (general styles that don't change regardless of dimensions)
2. Mobile
3. Tablet-small computer
4. Larger computers

The current method i have (using mobile as example) is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="style/mobile.css">
```

But this is not working on safari or firefox (have not tested other browsers) at all. I'm attempting to avoid jQuery, as I want a pure css solution, and am not worried about older browser support for this case. I've also tried using `max-width: 480px)` instead of `max-device-width`. Is there something I'm missing here?

**EDIT**

Also, to be clear, it is not loading the style sheets at all.

**EDIT 2**

I'd like to add that this is working for `min-width` I've currently got two sheets loading one for `1024px+` and one for `< 480px`, the `1024` is working fine, in between there are no styles, when I get below 480px there still aren't any styles.

```
      <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 1024px)" href="style/main.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 480px)" href="style/mobile.css">
```

All of the styles worked previously with just one css file, using media queries for the same purpose. My goal now is to break those up, especially to improve load time on mobile.

**HEAD SECTION**

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,100,300,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 1024px)" href="style/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 480px)" href="style/mobile.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/typography.css">
  </head>
```

Comment: Is it not loading at all or is it loading on devices/screens bigger than the max width set?

Comment: That's a good question, I should add that to my question. It's not loading at all.

Comment: Is it loading *any* stylesheets, even the "general" one? Can you show the actual, full document `head`? And if any of the sheets are loading, what device/specs are you testing under? As it is, you're asking us to imagine what *might* be happening if we *could* see the problem on some hypothetical device.

Comment: @PaulRoub see the second edit, the main stylesheet is working, the mobile is not. Also, I'm currently testing on my browser, by resizing (and reloading) locally.

Comment: Are you testing on a device with a high resolution screen? *For printers and very high resolution screens one CSS pixel implies multiple device pixels, so that the number of pixel per inch stays around 96.* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length

Comment: @BSMP I'm testing on a 27" imac 2014, with firefox, using the firesizer addon to display browser size. Testing between 2200px and 350px. I've also used safari with a similar plugin on the same device.

Comment: @BSMP I've also just uploaded it to a staging and tested on firefox for android, with the same results of no stylesheet (for that size).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did you try:

```
media="screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 480px)";
```

look at this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aPtA4nYkvDw

Comment: It's a decent tutorial, i love adam's stuff, unfortunately I don't want to depend on using `!important` tags, which will be necessary I think if i use `min-width: 0` for the mobile styles.

Comment: And I get what you're saying, im guessing someone downvoted you because it reads as something else. Might help to change it to `min-width: 0` to clarify. Someone would have to actually watch the tutorial to get your answer.

Comment: Your comment set me on the right path, so if you can change your answer to say `media="screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 480px)"` i'll accept it. For some reason it's only working if i have `min-width: 0px` in there with the `max-width`

Comment: _For some reason it's only working if i have min-width: 0px in there with the max-width_ That's so weird though. Is that because your other query used min-width?

Comment: Idk, that's a good question @BSMP, i should try removing it to see what happens. I've never had this issue before.

Answer (score 0):

Some devices apply a zoom to your page, so the perceived width is larger than the real one. Try adding this to your document's head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Thank you, i already have this though. I'm about to add my whole head section, should of done it sooner.

Answer (score 0):

how about removing the criteria from the link tag and use inline checks inside one style sheet for example

```
/* common rule(s) */
/* some rules here */

/* Css for Tablets*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {
  /* some rules here */
}

/* Css for Mini Tablets & Mobile */
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
   /* some rules here */
}

/* Css for Mobile */ 
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
    /* some rules here */
}
```

I've tried it without the !important tags but I think you should try it without the !important tag and see what happens, :) I hope you get through